# UK Rural and Urban Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I am looking for some reliable and potentially free data that divides the UK into rural, urban etc. sections:

https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/rural-urban-definition

the classification can either be associated with postcodes or wsg84 lat long borders.

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided links to some PDFs with colored maps (such as https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/427117/RUCLAD_leaflet_May2015.pdf)... I assume you're looking for machine-readable data?

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/389344/RUC11_LAD11_EN.csv/preview has a CSV download where you get the Local Authority name, ID, rural status, and other information. Using ArcGIS, qGIS, CartoDB, or something similar, you can join these attributes with a geography file.

Scotland and Northern Ireland have their own distribution departments. The details for Scotland can be found here:

http://www.gov.scot/Publications/2014/11/2763/downloads

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am looking for machine readable data.

Comment: @csetzkorn the csv should do it for you then

Comment: The data set is OK but incomplete. It definitely only covers England and not Scotland ...